# Best way to highlight certain elements in a figure?

Tags: highlights

I have a diagram and want to highlight several elements (if it makes any difference, it's around 75% of the total elements, and they are to be highlighted because they are included in a sample but they are not more important than other elements). I am trying to think of different ways to do this and came up with the following:

- bold
- italics
- underline
- highlighting the background
- some symbol

I wonder if, from a graphic designer's perspective, there are better and worse ways to do this. For example, if some methods may covey unwanted (mis)information, like using a sequential colour palette may imply a certain interpretation in a map. I think that, for example, italics may be a bad option since they usually have specific uses according to style guides.

I provide a picture similar to my diagram.

[image]

Comment: I think this is way too broad and opinion based. There are a billion different ways one could distinguish items in a list. In addition, without an *entire* picture of the project any opinion regarding a list may be inappropriate when considering overall design continuity for the project.

Comment: I was unsure of whether this was an acceptable question or not. It is indeed broad but the different choices can be argued for and against in somewhat objective ways, I believe. I am not a graphic designer myself so I wondered if there's any preference or standard.

Comment: While yes, your specific issue can not really be directly answered as Scott suggested, the more broader topic of font hierarchy is very interesting and in my opinion something that is definitely worth discussing here. As it is something that a lot of non-designers struggle with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't tell you what to do in your specific case, but I can give you some tips on how to work systematically towards finding a solution.

I notice that you are not showing the *actual* diagram, but have made some simplified example. That isn't always a good idea. With all respect, we often see that in questions posted by non-designers. This presupposes that design problems can always be reduced to a set of basic rules. But design often deals with *the complexity of the whole* and solutions often need to take several elements into account and find a compromise.

---

My suggestion is simply to make all the variations you can imagine and evaluate the results.

In my examples I also add a line explaining to the reader why some of the items look different than others.

#### Bold

[image]

This works OK, but perhaps the boldness makes the marked items look a little more important than others.

#### Italic

[image]

This is also a valid choice. Italic doesn't attract attention from a distance but the shift between regular and italic does introduce some unwanted wonkiness to the diagram.

#### Underline

[image]

This can be ruled out (pun intended) right away. Introducing more horizontal lines to a diagram containing lines just looks confusing.

#### Highlight

[image]

Highlighting with a background color really attracts attention to the marked items and looks a bit overwhelming, so I think we can ditch this.

#### Symbol left of diagram

[image]

I thought this would be a good idea, but it seems there's too much distance between the symbols and the words. It's hard to tell which items are marked.

#### Symbol left of text

[image]

This is just included for completeness. The words get different indents this way, and it all looks really messy.

#### Symbol right of text

[image]

This actually works quite well in my opinion. The items are clearly marked when you read them, but looking at the list as a whole, I don't think it's immediately apparent which words are marked.

---

I can't make the choice for you as I don't know anything about the context. I hope this way of going through the options can help you make a decision yourself.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, you made some points I wouldn't have thought of by myself, like avoiding introducing more lines. I also hadn't thought about the position of the symbol. And yes, I am more familiar with other SE communitites where it's desirable to post a simplified version.

Comment: You're welcome. About simplifying questions: I'm not sure we can make a rule. Sometimes, especially when asking more technical questions, it can be a good thing to isolate an issue. But we've just often seen questions here which are misunderstood because designers are used to zooming in on the specific problem at hand and are used to living with solutions not being universal. Also if you simplify something you might remove some of the factors you need to take into account.

Answer (score 0):

<sup>Maybe not a direct answer to your question but a more general guide when which emphasise method is appropriate.</sup>

---

### Text Structure

<sup>Why not to emphasise text:</sup>

| ✔ GOOD | ✕ BAD |
| --- | --- |
| **TITLES** Giving a text titles is often better than emphasising a word. **COLUMN BREAK** Having a lot of text in only one paragraph can make text look 'unappealing to read'. Use column breaks & paragraphs to segment your content. **LISTS** Are best used to: • Make information memorable • Group information • Give the reader an overview • Show an order or hierarchy. | Giving a text **titles** is often better than emphasising a word. Also having a lot of text in only one paragraph can make text look 'unappealing to read'. Use **column breaks & paragraphs** to segment your content. **Lists** are best used to: make information memorable, group information, give the reader an overview, or show an order, hierarchy or chronology. |

---

### Bold <sup><sub>/ Font Weights</sub></sup>

<sup>Focus on the important</sup>

| ✔ GOOD | ✕ BAD |
| --- | --- |
| Making words **bold** can guide the **focus** on important content. But making **everything in bold is bad**, as lighter font weight will stick out more at some point. | **Making words bold** can guide the focus on **important content**. **But making everything in bold is bad**, as lighter font weight will **stick out more** at some point. |

---

### Italic

<sup>Differentiate text parts with italic</sup>

| ✔ GOOD | ✕ BAD |
| --- | --- |
| To draw attention **italic font** is not ideal. <sub>I would say:</sub> *"Use italic to highlight quotes or to differentiate texts for example between narrator and protagonist.*" | To draw attention *italic font* is not ideal. <sub>I would say:</sub> **"use italic to highlight quotes or to differentiate texts for example between narrator and protagonist."** |

---

### Letter Case <sup><sub>/ Uppercase</sub></sup>

<sup>Sometimes you have to shout!</sup>

| ✔ GOOD | ✕ BAD |
| --- | --- |
| If you really want some attention you can use uppercase text like this: <sup><sub>**"GIVE THIS A LIKE!"**</sub></sup> – Especially in combination with bold it really shows off your desperation and anger (may not be appropriate some in cases ) <sub>**WHEN TO USE UPPERCASE?**</sub> It can be used if its size is also reduced or for short titles. | If you really want some attention you can use uppercase text like this: **"GIVE THIS A LIKE!"** – Especially in combination with bold it really shows off your desperation and anger (may not be appropriate some in cases ) **WHEN TO USE UPPERCASE?** It can be used if its size is also reduced or for short titles. |

---

### Underscored text

<sup>For highlighting links.</sup>

| ✔ GOOD | ✕ BAD |
| --- | --- |
| Underscored text <sup>¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯</sup> Should not really be used within text as it can be **mistaken for a link**. As dividers for titles it can be useful. | Underscored text <sup>¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯</sup> Should not really be used within text as it can be [mistaken for a link](https://thisisnotalink.text). As dividers for titles it can be useful. |

---

### Graphics

<sup>Make it more visual</sup>

| ✔ GOOD | ✕ BAD |
| --- | --- |
| [image] Using icons can be a **good idea**. As long as it helps to convey the message and icon set is uniform. But using too many icons can distract. | [image: -] Using icons can be a good idea. [image: -]As long as it helps to convey the message [image] And icon set is uniform. [image: -] But using too many icons can distract. |

---

### Whitespace

<sup>Highlight with pure nothingness.</sup>

| ✔ GOOD | ✕ BAD |
| --- | --- |
| Always remember that: **Whitespace is your friend!** And it plays a big role in the hierarchy of text/design elements in your layout. | Always remember that whitespace is your friend! And it plays a big role in the hierarchy of text/design elements in your layout. |

---

### Background

<sup>Highlight mistakes in text</sup>

| ✔ GOOD | ✕ BAD |
| --- | --- |
| Giving text a `background` can work if it is very light. Colours can quickly look too aggressive/trashy. Design-beginners should better not use this for various reasons. | Giving text a [image] can work if it is very light. Colours can quickly look too aggressive/trashy. Design-beginners should better not use this for various reasons. |

---

### Letter Spacing

<sup>Not suited for emphasising</sup>

| ✔ GOOD | ✕ BAD |
| --- | --- |
| Many non-designers use spaced out letters to highlight text. Don't do that please – It hurts my eyes. | Many non-designers use S p a c e d O u t L e t t e r s to highlight text. Don't do that please – It hurts my eyes. |

---

Comment: Wow, *tables*! Not a common sight here. 

Comment: I want to revive the table design movement  (mostly was thinking I try out some stuff – there's some insane things in there when you look at the markup source code)